# Inverse And operation

Tags: disassembly, assembly, c, patch-reversing, xor

I'm trying to write a keygen to a crack me that I'm learning from and I got stuck. What happens there is pretty simple:

Let's say that I entered the password: "12121212"

```
XOR DWORD PTR DS:[ECX+EAX],1234567
AND BYTE PTR DS:[ECX+EAX],0E
ADD ECX,4
CMP ECX,8
```

As we can see, the first `DWORD` of the password (`0x32313231`, *notice that x86 processors use* [*little-endian layout*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)) is being `XORed` with `0x1234567` so `0x32313231 ^ 0x1234567` results with `0x56771233`.
Then there is an `AND` operation on the first byte (`0x56`) of the manipulated password and `0xe` which results with `0x6`. After that, the program repeats the operations, this time on the second `DWORD` of the password.

My question is: I know I can reverse `XOR` but is it possible with `AND` operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there's no way to know with 100% certainty what was the original value before the AND operation, you can find some *possible* values producing the same result, and sometimes that's enough.

Basically, for `x & N = z`, you can start from `z` and set any bits to `1` where you have are 0 in `N`. `z` itself will always work too.

For example, if we know that `x & 0xE == 6`, then at any of the following values of `x` will work: 6,7, 0x16, 0x17, 0x26, 0x27 and so on.

Comment: This answer helps me a lot!

Answer (score 5):

The answer is **no**. Unlike bitwise `XOR`, bitwise `AND` can't be reversed:

```
0 & 1 = 0
0 & 0 = 0
```

Both `AND` and `OR` are not reversible. This is in contrast to `XOR` and `NOT` operators which are reversible.